# Do I need an iOS device to 'Archive' Xcode Project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a rookie iOS developer trying to launch my first app, I've been digging on StackOverflow for long to find answers - but none worked.
There are 3 key points to bear in mind...

1. I don't actually own an iOS device, so far I've just been using simulators to test the app
2. I have all certificates and provisioning ones too.
3. I've already created a profile on iTunes Connect to upload my project into.

**So here are the problems**

[image: This is a screenshot of the errors that I've been getting.]

1. It says that I need to plug in a device and have Xcode register it, but I don't have an iOS device at all.
2. I've created the certificates and all needed in Developer.Apple.com so why is it saying it couldn't find any?
3. I also get an additional error, here are the errors:

[image: All errors]

Just to let you know, I honestly have been scouring this site for answers, trying all I could but the 3 errors above simply don't go away.

**I'm ready to publish the app, but it just won't 'Archive' :(**
Please help!

Comment: Your errors are code signing errors. After you have fixed them, you can archive the app without a device by using using "Generic iOS Device" from the target dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't need a real device to publish an app

The problem you're facing is choosing the right provisioning profile. You need to create:
 + A Production Certificate
 + An AppID match with your app bundle
 + A Production Provisioning profile from your Cert & AppID

I recommend you should read carefully to understand what is provisioning profile: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

and how to publish app
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812

Good luck

Comment: Here's what I've just done... I relinked my account to Xcode and unchecked the box to 'Automatically manage signing' - now I get just this error... Provisioning profile "App Name" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution:

Comment: short answer: re-generate your "iPhone Distribution" with "App Name" included.

long answer: read apple document to understand how Certificate, AppID and DeviceID combined to make Provisioning Profile and you will never facing these kind of issues anymore :)

Comment: It seems as if you're wrong - Xcode is demanding an iOS device to be connected and a provisioning file to be added too. Apparently, it's used to verify that the developer did in fact create the project.